# access the value of the key outside of for loop when key's value in the loop equals the key Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, mapreduce

I have two list of dictionaries:

```
sftoap = [{'0060z000023GQYKAA4': 'ID-2522'}, 
{'0060z000023GQZNAA4': 'ID-2523'}, 
{'0060z000023GQidAAG': 'ID-2524'}]

opp_products = [{'Opportunity_ID__c': '0060z000023GQYKAA4', 'TotalPrice': 50408.22991509}, 
{'Opportunity_ID__c': '0060z000023GQZNAA4', 'TotalPrice': 50408.22991509},
{'Opportunity_ID__c': '0060z000023GQighTY', 'TotalPrice': 50408.22991509}]
```

I need to loop through `opp_products` and assign a key's value from `sftoap` list of dictionaries to a new variable. BUT Only if the value of 'Opportunity_ID__c' equals to the key from `sftoap`

Here is what I have tried:

```
for index, opp_products_dict in enumerate(opp_products):
    for opp_products_key, opp_products_value in opp_products_dict.items():
        id = opp_products_dict["Opportunity_ID__c"]
        ap_opp_id = sftoap[id]
```

Gives me an error, because I clearly need to loop through the `sftoap` But don't want to have nested loops. My desired output would be:

```
print(ap_opp_id)
ID-2522
ID-2524
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid a nested loop, you could create a dictionary from `sftoap` before you enter the loop, like this:

```
sftoap_dict = {}
for d in sftoap:
    key, value = d.popitem()
    sftoap_dict[key] = value
```

This way you can use `ap_opp_id = sftoap_dict[id]` in your original loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can reorganize your sftoap list of dictionaries to a dictionary to avoid nested loop.
for example:

```
sftoap_dict = {}
for dicts in sftoap:
    for key,val in dicts.items():
        sftoap_dict[key]=val
```

Next, you could include exception in the second part of your code

```
 for index, opp_products_dict in enumerate(opp_products):
    for opp_products_key, opp_products_value in opp_products_dict.items():
        idx = opp_products_dict["Opportunity_ID__c"]
        try:
            ap_opp_id = sftoap_dict[idx]
            print(ap_opp_id)
        except KeyError:
            pass
```